# which word is correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I'm a English-learner. Today I do TOEIC examination questions. there is a one confused me!

> Our manager, Mr. Mullins, is admired for _____ his employees to exceed
>   their own limitations.
>  (a) motivation
>   (b) motivate 
>  (c) motivating
>   (d) motivated

The answer is (c), but I don't know why!

Answer (score 1):

The key here is the use of the preposition **for**.

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

[**For + -ing: reason**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/for-ing)

> We use **for** + the -ing form of a verb to refer to **the reason** for
>   something:
>
> *You should talk to Jane about it. You know, she’s famous **for being** a
>   good listener*

In your sentence it's explained **why** Mr.Mullins is admired, **the reason**.

> Our manager, Mr. Mullins, is admired **for motivating** his employees to
>   exceed their own limitations.

Notice that **for** must be followed by a verb in its **gerund** form. Option (a) is a noun. And (b) and (d) are verb forms but not gerunds.